# How to return multiple recordsets in a single execution using ADODB?

Tags: sql, vba, adodb

I need to iterate through multiple recodsets produced by a single query.

However my current connection does not seem to support doing this. So when I do .NextRecordset I get the message:

> Current provider does not support returning multiple recordsets from a
>   single execution

This is my connection string:

```
DB_CONNECTION = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Forecasting;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
Call Conn.Open(DB_CONNECTION)
```

What must I do to be able to use .NextRecordset?

Comment: I've never seen a provider that supported multiple recordsets.

Comment: that's weird, I mean what is the NextRecordset method used for then?

Comment: I imagine that MS added it in case providers were interested in providing the capability to be able to return multiple result sets. In my experience, it's just not something that ADODB providers ever popularly supported. Just as fast to fire off another query... often, that second query differs upon the results of the first query anyway.

Comment: what does your query look like? are there separate statements like `Select 1 from Table1; Select 2 from Table2`?

Comment: The MS sample code uses SQL server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677569(v=vs.85).aspx  And Access: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243535(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: @TimWilliams Huh.. so according to that, the `sqloledb provider` supports it.

Comment: @lisovaccaro - you should add more details to your question.

Answer (score 5):

Set the CursorLocation to **adUseServer** (instead of 'client side' )

```vb
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
strSQL = "Select * from States; Select * from Countries;"

With RS
   .CursorLocation = adUseServer
   .ActiveConnection = DB_CONNECTION
   .CursorType = adOpenStatic
   .Open strSQL
End With

Do
   If Not RS.EOF Then
       'do something
   End If
   Set RS = RS.NextRecordset
   If RS Is Nothing Then
       Exit Do
   End If
Loop Until RS.State = adStateClosed
```